# How to get System/Disk Informations using Lotus script?

Tags: lotusscript

I want to get current PC's system information(like OS, Version and Processor names).
Any one know solution to this problem, please guide me.

Thanks,
Krishna

Comment: Remember to accept correct answers to your already answered questions. That keeps people happy and motivates them to answer your future questions.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/Search/2b812ddff112ee7585256ad1006f5381?OpenDocument

and this:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/Search/e0d4e80defff55b385256a31004d590e?OpenDocument